# Firefox combining 'Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade' conflicts with mobile operator proxy

Tags: javascript, websocket, http-headers, keep-alive

I have a WebSocketServer running on a server box, with a website attempting to connect to it and send back and forth information.

I have noticed that on WiFi it works perfectly on all the browsers I have tested, however over Mobile Data Firefox. I intercepted and edited headers and managed to reproduce the problem. Firefox is sending a combined header `Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade` in the request. Chrome in comparison is just sending `Connection: Upgrade`. My theory is that when the request passes through the mobile data provider's proxy, as well as adding their own identifying headers, it re-parses all of the other headers, and does not understand a combined header. This is confirmed by the fact that at the server end, the request is received (from Firefox) but the `Connection` header is truncated to `Connection: keep-alive`. If I manually remove the `keep-alive` from the `Connection` header using the interception program, the problem is solved.

I don't need the `keep-alive` part of the request (in fact if anything I would prefer it not to be enabled) so I'm asking if there is a way to stop Firefox sending it without using about:config etc (e.g. in JS or HTML), as I would like for this to work for the general end-user.

Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: I just arrived to the same conlusion as yours. What did you do finally?

Comment: Unfortunately I never found the solution to this. The benefits of WebSockets were less important to me than the ability for the system to work for everyone, so I ended up resorting to making many AJAX requests. Sorry I can't be of more help...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am on it since one month, keep investigating and I may not be so far from finding the answer. I will keep you informed FYI.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, henceforth resolved.

In my case, the problem was that my hosting provider had a proxy which was not dealing correctly with the `Connection` and/or `Upgrade` headers. Indeed, these headers are [hop-by-hop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hop-by-hop_transport) and as such:

> **Hop-by-hop headers**
>   are meaningful only for a single transport-level connection and ***must not be retransmitted*** by proxies or cached. Such headers are: Connection, Keep-Alive, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authorization, TE, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding and Upgrade. Note that only hop-by-hop headers may be set using the Connection general header.

*Souce: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers*

Shortly, these headers are not retransmitted but somehow interpreted before being passed to your server. When these headers are sent by Firefox, this phase of interpretation becomes critical since the value associated to the `Connection` header is more "complicated" than that sent by other browsers, i.e.

Firefox sends `Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade`

Chrome/Edge/... sends `Connection: Upgrade`

---

**Solution** : I simply told my hosting provider that only `Connection: keep alive` arrives to my server when one sends `Upgrade: <my_protocole>` **AND** `Connection: keep alive, Upgrade` *(and he had the possibility to correct the issu within 72 hours)*.